# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 30470400 into shape (50,1104,104)

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am trying to run threw this Tutorial 
http://emmanuelle.github.io/segmentation-of-3-d-tomography-images-with-python-and-scikit-image.html

where I want to do a Segmentation of 3-D tomography images with Python.

I'm struggling directly in the beginning, with reshaping the image.

This is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import time as time 

data = np.fromfile('/data/data_l67/dalladas/Python3/Daten/Al8Cu_1000_g13_t4_200_250.vol', dtype=np.float32)

data.shape

(60940800,)

data.reshape((50,1104,104))
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 data.reshape((50,1104,104))
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 30470400 into shape
>   (50,1104,104)

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Try `a.reshape(50, 1104, -1) ` which will figure out 3rd dim automagically

Comment: [code to find the all possible reshape values for the given image shape.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225425/14896907)

Answer (score 26):

It seems that there is a typo, since `1104*1104*50=60940800` and you are trying to reshape to dimensions `50,1104,104`. So it seems that you need to change 104 to 1104.

Answer (score 13):

In Matrix terms, the number of elements always has to equal the product of the number of rows and columns. In this particular case, the condition is not matching.

Answer (score 9):

```
data.reshape((50,1104,-1))
```

works for me