# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 14333830 into shape (14130,1,1286), how do I solve this?

Tags: python-3.x

Getting this error in python:

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 14333830 into shape (14130,1,1286)`,

How do I solve this?

This is the code generating the error:
data_train1=data_train.reshape(14130,1,1286)

Comment: Please include the code that caused the error.

Comment: data_train1=data_train.reshape(14130,1,1286)

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947298/valueerror-cannot-reshape-array-of-size-30470400-into-shape-50-1104-104)

Answer (score 0):

For doing reshaping, your new shape should match the previous shape. If you multiply 14130 * 1286, you get 18171180 which is obviously not the same as 14333830. So you must write something correct.