# Can not reshape 2 dimensional array to 3 dimensional array for RNN in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I can not reshape the array into 3-dimensional one. Here is the example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {
"a": [0.06 , 0.07, 0.45, 0.98, 0.97 ],
"b": [12,45,65, 56, 34],
"c": [2,5,5, 5, 3],
"d": [23,55,25, 15, 34],
"e": [0.0005,0.55555,0.383825, 0.4747477415, 0.348344334],
"f": [0.0236 , 0.3407, 0.4545, 0.9658, 0.4597 ],
"g": [70 , 90, 123, 154, 99 ],    
}

#load into df:
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(df)
```

```
df.shape

X = df[['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f']].to_numpy()
y = df['g'].to_numpy()

X
```

This is what I found as a possible solution from one of the [stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947298/valueerror-cannot-reshape-array-of-size-30470400-into-shape-50-1104-104)

```
# Reshaping the X data to be 3D
X = X.reshape(5, 7, -1)
```

But it did not work for me. I understand that matrix has its rules, however, is it possible to convert it into three dimensional array? Could you help me if you know? Thank you very much!

I want to get something like (5,7,3). The array that end with the 3.

Comment: Can you provide the explicit expected output 3D array given your input?

Comment: I was following the code from this kaggle notebook https://www.kaggle.com/code/mikoajfish99/simple-rnn-forecasting-price-of-a-house

I wanted to reshape so that I can get something like this:
X_train shape: (312, 1, 3)
X_test shape: (35, 1, 3)
y_train shape: (312,)
y_test shape: (35,)

Which I could use for the lstm modeling

Comment: something like reshaping what I have to (*, *, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do:

```
X = df[['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f']].to_numpy()
y = df['g'].to_numpy()
```

X.shape is `(5, 6)`

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f']].to_numpy().reshape(5,6,-1)
```

Since you have moved `'g'` out to `y`

```
X = X.reshape(5, 6, -1)
```

Other variants are:

```
X=X.reshape(2, 5, 3)
X=X.reshape(5, 2, 3)
X=X.reshape(10, 1, 3)
X=X.reshape(1, 10, 3)
```

How we get them, actually the product of these numbers should be the product of shape. So, in this case product of `(5,6)` is `30`.

Now, you want a 3D array with `3` at the end, so we need 10 from the first 2 dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, but did not work for me. I wanted something that transform my array (5,6) to something (*, *, 3). Where * is a number. Do you know what we can do with it?

Comment: What about `(2,5,3)` , `(5,2,3)`,`(10,1,3)`, or `(1,10,3)`?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. May  you have a wonderful day!